# Python proxy HTTP very slow

Tags: python, http, proxy

I'm trying to create a HTTP proxy with Python.

Although, when I configure my browser with this proxy and try to connect to a http website, the loading is very slow.

This is my proxy code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import thread
import sys

def get_line(field, data) :
    lines = data.split("\n")
    for line in lines :
        if line.split(":")[0] == field :
            return line
    return ""

def get_host(data) :
    host_line = get_line("Host", data);
    port = 80
    if len(host_line.split(" ")) > 1 :
        host = host_line.split(" ")[1]
        arr = host.split(":")
        if len(arr) > 1 :
            host = arr[0]
            port = arr[1]
        else :
            host = host[:-1]
    else :
        host = ""
        port = 0
    return (host, port)

def http_proxy(conn, data, client_addr) :
    (host, port) = get_host(data)
    if host != "" :
        try :
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((socket.gethostbyname(host), int(port)))
            s.send(data)
            while 1 : 
                reply = s.recv(8192)
                test = reply
                if (len(reply) > 0) :
                    conn.send(reply)
                    print "Send %d bytes from %s" % (len(reply), host)
                else :
                    conn.close()
                    s.close()
                    break
        except socket.error, (value, message) :
            s.close()
            conn.close()
            print value, message
            sys.exit(1)

def main():
    try :
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(('', 8080))
        s.listen(100)
    except socket.error, (value, message) :
        if s : 
            s.close()
        print "Socket error : ", message
    while 1 :
        conn, client_addr = s.accept()
        data = conn.recv(8192)
        thread.start_new_thread(http_proxy, (conn, data, client_addr))
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

I think these delays are caused by the fact that some HTTP requests are not taken into account by my proxy, so the browser waits a certain time before sending them back.

If that's the problem, I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: things to try first:  get rid of the socket.gethostbyname(host) call.   Also your recv/send calls are not used reliably; your code doesn't take into account that recv() may not return all 8192 bytes asked for, likewise send may not send everything you ask it to. Read up on their API. (they return the actual number of bytes received/sent).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have tried to replace this line :
s.connect((socket.gethostbyname(host), int(port)))

by:
s.connect((host, int(port)))

But I still have the problem.

I have read the documentation of recv : https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example

It does not seem to me that recv returns the number of characters received.

Comment: I also tried to replace this line :
if (len(reply) > 0) :

by : 
if reply :

(like example)
But the problem also persists.

Comment: Unfortunately the examples there are too simplistic - they ignore many low level aspects of socket i/o. You should probably read up on the actual socket functions and how they work on a low level.  Furthermore HTTP is a complex protocol so there are many intricacies involved creating a working proxy server